# Prove existence and uniqueness $f\in C([0,1])$ such that $f(t)+\frac{t}{2}\cos(f(t))=\int_0^1f(ts)s^2ds$

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, integral-equations

Prove there is a unique $f\in C([0,1])$ such that
$$
f(t)+\frac{t}{2}\cos(f(t))=\int_0^1f(ts)s^2ds.
$$

Any idea how to approach the problem ?

I considered to use banach-theorem(fixed-point) but I am not entirly sure how to approach it.

**Edit :**

My attempt:

Let  $f,g\in C([0,1])$ such that

$f(t)=(Tf)(t):=\int_0^1f(ts)s^2ds-\frac{t}{2}\cos(f(t)), g(t)=\int_0^1g(ts)s^2ds-\frac{t}{2}\cos(g(t))$.

$|(Tf)(t)-(Tg)(t)|\le |\int_0^1(f(ts)-g(ts))s^2ds|+\frac{t}{2}|\cos(f(t))-\cos(g(t))|\leq \int_0^1|f(ts)-g(ts)|s^2ds+\frac{t}{2}|f(t)-g(t)|$

How to continue ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Shouldn't be $f(s)$ in the integral of the title?

Comment: yes , fixed thanks

Comment: The Banach fixed point theorem should be effective for the operator $-{t\over 2}\cos f(t)+\int_0^1 \ldots $ The operator is contractive with a constant ${1\over 2}+{1\over 3}.$

Comment: @CSquared the OP mentioned a fixed-point theorem already

Comment: The integral is bounded by $\|f-g\|\int_0^1s^2\,ds={1\over 3}\|f-g\|.$ The second term by ${1\over 2}\|f-g\|.$ There were some misprints in your estimates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(Tf)(t)=\int\limits_0^1f(ts)s^2\,ds -{t\over 2}\cos f(t).$
Then
$$|(Tf)(t)-(Tg)(t)|\le \int\limits_0^1|f(ts)-g(ts)|s^2\,ds+{1\over 2}|\cos f(t)-\cos g(t)|\\
\le \|f-g\|\int\limits_0^1s^2\,ds +{1\over 2}\|f-g\|={5\over 6}\|f-g\|$$
Hence $\|Tf-Tg\|\le {5\over 6}\|f-g\|,$ and the Banach fixed point theorem can be applied.